# which is better initializing global/static variables to zero or keep them uninitialized

Tags: c

1) While declaring global & static variables, should we initialize them to 0? Though by default they will be initialized to 0, is there any recommended approach?

2) Should we keep them uninitialized (where they go to BSS section) or initialize them to 0 (where they go to data section of memory)? Will that (which area of memory they go to) have any impact? Will keeping them uninitialized result in small size of binary image of program (if yes, please let me know how it will result in small size & can this be a reason to keep them uninitialized)?

3) Does C coding standard say anything about it, OR there are any pros & cons of preferring one approach over the another?

Comment: all global variables are zero initialized.

Comment: try to avoid global variables as much as possible.

Comment: There is no such thing as an uninitialised global variable; as you say, they are default-initialised to 0.

Comment: @codemonkey: Except that's wrong.

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_. Also, _what_ "coding standard"?

Comment: @codemonkey Global variables are always initialized, thus they should never lead to undefined behavoir.

Comment: Ad (2), I'm surprised GCC in fact generates different code for `int foo;` and `int foo = 0;`. Interesting.

Comment: @mafso: gcc without optimizations is not a good compiler. And when we enable optimizations, they will both arrive in the BSS. https://gist.github.com/sharth/5b5535d831efda713066

Comment: @BillLynch: I meant the object files differ before linking (and this is still true with optimizations). And there seems to be some semantic difference for gcc, see my answer below (which also works with optimizations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decent compiler should treat these two global variables identically:

```
int x;
int y = 0;
```

It should also treat these two static variables identically:

```
int f() {
    static int x;
    static int y = 0;
}
```

By identically, I mean that they will have the same value and be be stored in the same program segment. You should use the one that you find most readable.

As to if this takes up less space in your executable, that would depend on your executable format. For elf, which is common on linux and other unixes, the answer would be that a zero-initialized variable would take up less space. That means that:

```
static int x;     // no space.
static int y = 0; // no space.
static int z = 1; // takes space.
```

Comment: (1) Wont x go to bss and y to data section ? you said above both will goto same segment. can you plz clarify on this. (2)Which option is preferable & why?

Comment: Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/sharth/5b5535d831efda713066 I compiled it with `gcc -O3 foo.c`. The four variables are all in the BSS as confirmed by `nm`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/10/gnu-binutils-collection-of-binary-tools/ has similar example for global variable one init'd & other uninit'd but stored in data & bss section resp. While as you pointed, they are always stored in bss. Any idea on why this difference ? Thanks again.

Comment: That website is partially wrong with their explanations. `global_int1` and `global_string` are initialized. They are zero-initialized. `global_int2` is not zero-initialized, because it has been set to 10. So `global_int2` won't be in the BSS. Likewise, `const_int` is also not zero-initialized, so it won't be in the BSS.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be asking: "is it a recommended convention to explicitly initialise objects of static storage duration to zero, even though they will be zero-initialised regardless?"

If my interpretation is correct, the answer is a firm **no**.

There may be some coding standard in some company somewhere that recommends it, but it's a silly recommendation.

As for the area of memory they end up in, whether you initialize them manually has absolutely nothing at all to do with it.

Comment: 1) yes your interpretation is correct. Can you let me know the reasons for "firm no". (2)Uninitialized variables go to BSS section of memory while initialized ones to data section of memory (plz correct me if i am wrong here). In that case, initializing or keeping them uninitialized will decide on which memory area they will go to. Right ?

Comment: @user1182722: "Reasons"? It's self-evident. Why would the general populace recommend doing something that you don't have to and that has no effect whatsoever?

Comment: Will keeping them uninitialized result in small size of binary image of program (if yes, plz let me know how it will result in small size & can this be another reason to keep them uninitialized) ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 'cos they do. Same reason as the cargo-cult 'bzero' on so many network buffers - someone posted it decades ago, and shit propagates..

Comment: @user1182722: Are you actually experiencing some problem that you're trying to solve? Your continual stream of questions is open-ended and conversational. Perhaps you got lost on your way to a chatroom!

Answer (score 3):

Not initializing them explicitly is common. Maybe there are coding style guidelines recommending explicit initialization.

There is one technical difference mandated by the C standard: If a variable is initialized implicitly (a "tentative definition"), it can be initialized explicitly later:

```
int foo;
int foo = 1; // valid

int bar = 0;
int bar = 0; // invalid, even though initialized to the same value
```

This also applies to array sizes (they default to one element), where I would consider it a misfeature and recommend giving the size explicitly. But that's basically a matter of taste.

The C standard doesn't know anything about memory sections; default-initialized and explicitly initialized variables don't make a difference for strictly conforming code. For GCC, there seems to be some difference (for non-portable code). The following is undefined by the C standard, but GCC (tested with GNU `ld` on Linux, x86 32-bit, ELF) accepts it:

**foo.c**

```
int foo = 42;
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo;

int main(void) { printf("%d\n", foo); }
```

Compiles and links with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` and outputs 42 when run. When `foo` is initialized explicitly in **main.c**, the linker fails, complaining about multiple definitions of `foo`. I couldn't find something about this in the GCC docs, but the C standard (C11, n1570 draft) lists under "common extensions" (J.5.11 p1):

> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword `extern`; if the definitions disagree, or more than 
>   one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

For the generated ELFs, I couldn't find any difference on my platform (though I just experimented, as said above, I can't find where this behaviour is documented), so the difference seems only semantically (and only for non-portable code) with no difference in efficiency.

Comment: Related: Gcc options `-fcommon`/`-fno-common`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28165107/1741125).

Answer (score 2):

1.As a matter of style and practice it is good to initialize them to 0.

2.uninitialized data doesn't occupy any space in executable format so as zero initialized ones ( as the   OS loader has the responsibility to allocate a Zero initialized memory for this area). The elf header only saves the total space required for the uninitialized area.

3.C standard mandates that the global/static variables to be initialized to zero.

Note that in embedded systems which doesn't have a mechanism to dynamically create process/threads, it is the responsibility of the start-up code to initialize the global/static to zero and for performance considerations it is possible to initialize areas as required. note that this form of implementation is not conforming to the C standard, might help to improve the boot-up time.

Comment: Will keeping them uninitialized result in small size of binary image of program (if yes, plz let me know how it will result in small size & can this be a reason to keep them uninitialized) ?

Comment: for the initialized variable to initialize properly ,the elf has to store the initial value, where as in uninitialized or zero case it is known to be zero.

Comment: in modern compilers there are options by which the initialized data segment can be compressed to reduce the binary size and later decompressed (by start-up code or OS loader).

Answer (score 2):

It will be well and good to initialize the variables that you're using in your program. If you don't initialize them, there is a danger of ending up taking "garbage values" from your variables.

However, in the case of global variables, as they are automatically initialized to zero there is no need to initialize them to zero yourself.

Based on what I've learnt so far from lectures on computer programming, using global variables is not a good way of programming, because variables should always have the smallest scope possible. The argument behind that is that every time you increase the scope you have more code that potentially modifies the variable, thus more complexity is induced in the solution. In the case of local variables, their scope is limited and it is mandatory to initialize them, otherwise there is a danger that you will be using "garbage values".