# an expected “duplicate symbol” doesn't happen when missing “extern”

Tags: c

In file1.c

```
int i;
foo1()
{
.....
}
```

In file2.c

```
int i=10;
foo2()
{
.....
}
```

Then when I `gcc file1.c file2.c` .It was made succeed which I think is impossible because I believe there will be an `duplicate symbol` from complier.
So can anyone tell me why my code was built successfully without using "`extern`"? And is there any difference between C and C++ in this situation?

Comment: `C` or `C++` - your question is related to which language?

Comment: you may get a "duplicate symbol" from the linker, not from the compiler. The compiler doesn't know, when compiling each of the files, that a variable with the same name exists on another file unless you declare it in the header and include the header.

Comment: @Joao I think when I run "gcc file1.c file2.c" ,the linker will check if all the symbol are duplicated or not. So why the linker doesn't throw any error or warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is invalid. A GCC extension allows GCC to accept it.

To turn the extension off, use the flag `-fno-common`.

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) says:

> `-fno-common`
>
> > In C code, controls the placement of uninitialized global variables. Unix C compilers have traditionally permitted multiple definitions of such variables in different compilation units by placing the variables in a common block. This is the behavior specified by `-fcommon`, and is the default for GCC on most targets. On the other hand, this behavior is not required by ISO C, and on some targets may carry a speed or code size penalty on variable references. The `-fno-common` option specifies that the compiler should place uninitialized global variables in the data section of the object file, rather than generating them as common blocks. This has the effect that if the same variable is declared (without `extern`) in two different compilations, you get a multiple-definition error when you link them. In this case, you must compile with `-fcommon` instead. Compiling with `-fno-common` is useful on targets for which it provides better performance, or if you wish to verify that the program will work on other systems that always treat uninitialized variable declarations this way.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, you are right: this is an error. But most C implementations support it as an extension (at least by default). C99 actually mentions it in informative Annex J as a common extension

> **J.5.11 Multiple external definitions**
>
> 1 There may be more than one
> external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without
> the explicit use of the keyword **extern**; if the definitions disagree,
> or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2)